# Wxpython is returning a DLL error on windows 10

Tags: python, dll, wxpython

I'm trying to make a simple GUI application using Python and I chose **wxPython** to make it, one of the reasons is the **large amount of tutorials**, since I don't have any knowlegde about it. The problem is I can't even import wxPython on my program. This is an old problem and there are some solutions here, but none of them worked for me.

Here's my problem, this error appears whenever I try to import wxPython (even in the interpreter).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/mari_/PycharmProjects/trab_FBD/proprietario.py", line 2, in <module>
    import wx
  File "C:\Users\mari_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wx\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *
  File "C:\Users\mari_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

I'm using Pycharm, but I've already installed wxPython in my main interpreter, as well as on the venv's.

I would like to use wxPython, but I accept other GUI recomendations.

I've already tried to use PyInstaller, but it didn't work, the same result when I tried to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package.

Comment: How did you installed wxpython? try with this: pip install -U wxPython.
This should install the DLL files as well.

Comment: @AttilaToth I've already tried this, isn't working =/.

Comment: It seems you doing all wrong/assuming wrong things. 1) What Python distro are you using? If it is conda, try [this](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/wxpython) I do not use conda, and cannot give you advise how to activate the instance you want to install into. 2) PyInstaller **creates** Python executables, it is not about installing Python 3) VC++ 2008 Redistributable is for Python 2.7. For >3.4 you would need Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable.

Comment: @nepix32 I'm using Python 3.7, I don't use Conda either. About PyInstaller, I used it to create an executable, but when I run it, the same problem persist. I've installed Visual C++ 2015 but the same DLL error is appearing. EDIT: Just installed x86 version of Visual C++ 2015 and it's working. Thank you!